# How to change the width of a CSS flex-box column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a ***menu*** div that fills 100% of its container height, and beside it, to the right, are the ***header***, ***body*** and ***footer*** sections.

I managed to do this with the `CSS flex property`. However, I want to change the amount of width the `"menu"` div takes out of the container, as in, making it `10% width of container's width`, and make the `rest divs fill what's left` (even if the `"menu"` div is hidden at a later time).

JS Fiddle of what I have right now: https://jsfiddle.net/jf29vr0x/3/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  width: 75%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.header {
  flex: 0 0 10%;
  background: lightgray;
}

.body {
  flex: 0 0 80%;
  background: purple;
}

.footer {
  flex: 0 0 10%;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="menu">
    Menu
  </div>

  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>

  <div class="body">
    Body
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    Footer
  </div>

</div>
```

I found that if I set the width explicitly on the "menu" class, it resizes it, but the rest of the boxes don't fill the space left, unless I also explicitly state their width to 100%. However, doing this, makes the container overflow, and because the container is aligned to the center, it looks off.

I could also set the width to 90% (on header, footer body) and 10% on the menu, but the menu is sometimes set to `display: none;`, so when it disappears, the other layout parts are only going to be 90% of container's width.

Is there any way of doing this with only flex-box properties? I don't understand very well what flex-shrink and flex-grow are about, but I think they only affect (in this case) the height?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this work out for you? https://jsfiddle.net/jf29vr0x/6/ remove the display none and show the display inline-block

made it so that it overflows with the 100% width on the header/body/footer but the overflow is hidden, and when the menu is set to display none, there is no overflow in effect.

otherwise, flex might not be your answer or JS is required

Comment: Hmm, the thing is that if you text-align: right or text-align: center the text on the header div, for instance, then the text is off or disappears completely (because it goes over to the hidden overflow). Like in here: https://jsfiddle.net/jf29vr0x/8/ . I guess maybe flex-boxes wouldn't work for this then, it would be cool if you could set both width and height on them though, despite of if they are rows or columns...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add a wrapper around the right column, and then only specify `flex-basis` on the `.menu` element.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 75%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.right-col {
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.menu {
  flex-basis: 10%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.header {
  flex: 0 0 10%;
  background: lightgray;
}

.body {
  flex: 0 0 80%;
  background: purple;
}

.footer {
  flex: 0 0 10%;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">Menu</div>
  <div class="right-col">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="body">Body</div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jf29vr0x/11/

Now when the menu is hidden, the right column expands the full amount.

Comment: Great, that works as expected! I hadn't even thought about adding a wrapper. Thank you.