# CSS Flex full height sidebar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make sidebar with background, where its height is same as height of **#page-content** but I can't make it work. The Sidebar height is still same as its content.

Here is the css code:

```
.flexbox {
    display: -webkit-flex !important;
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
.flexbox .flexbox-col {
    flex: 1;
}


<div id="mainWrapper" class="main-grid clearfix flexbox">
   <div id="sidebar" class="opened left flexbox-col"></div> 
   <div id="page-content" class="page-content flexbox-col">
</div>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28998490/how-to-change-the-width-of-a-css-flex-box-column/

Comment: FWIW I feel `!important` can be a useful tool in the toolbox. If you're structuring your stylesheets with ITCSS, your `.flexbox` class fits neatly into ["trumps" category](https://medium.com/@pistenprinz/css-at-trivago-part-1-structure-and-itcss-52f63ed557ca#fb16)

Answer (score 0):

These elements don't have a height unless you tell them to have one unless there is content.

If you want elements to have a 100% height, add that to your CSS.

**Also**,you really shouldn't be using `!important` that much.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.flexbox {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox, display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
.flexbox .flexbox-col {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}
#sidebar {
  background: #f00;
}
#page-content {
  background: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainWrapper" class="main-grid clearfix flexbox">
  <div id="sidebar" class="opened left flexbox-col"></div>
  <div id="page-content" class="page-content flexbox-col"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Paulie_D. !important I used, because I wasn't sure, if display: flex isn't somewhere overwritten. Anyway, I tried to use your code and sidebar has still its' own height :/

Comment: You want to set the .flexbox to min-height: 100%; Not height 100%. This way if the content in page-content is larger than the screen the sidebar will still take up all the vertical space.

Answer (score -1):

Following codepen (http://codepen.io/Kebten/pen/PqNVrW) has a sidebar with a list that takes up the vertical space available - i'm assuming this was the point of your question :-)

Background colours added as an aid.

```
<div id="mainWrapper" class="main-grid clearfix flexbox">
    <div id="sidebar" class="opened left flexbox-col">
        <ul>
            <li>sidebar</li>
            <li>sidebar</li>
            <li>sidebar</li>
            <li>sidebar</li>
            <li>sidebar</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="page-content" class="page-content flexbox-col">
        <ul>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
            <li>content</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

#sidebar {
    background-color: pink;
}
#page-content {
    background-color: green;
}
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
}
.flexbox .flexbox-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
}
#sidebar ul {
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
#sidebar ul li {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
#page-content ul {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

HTML seemed to be missing a div, but didn't seem to affect results.